# WCF - Рассылка сообщений сервером

Tags: c#, wcf

Клиенты должны получать сообщение(одинаковое), которое рассылается с сервера, как можно это реализовать? Понимаю когда клиент может получать ответ на запрос от сервера, но как сделать принудительную(от сервера) рассылку не могу найти информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю вам нужно  [Duplex Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract).`Duplex Contract` позволяет клиентам и серверам взаимодействовать друг с другом независимо (клиент может инициировать вызовы сервера, а сервер - вызовы клиента). `Duplex Contract`- это одна из трех схем обмена сообщениями, доступных для служб `Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)`.

Comment: минус то зачем?